# deploy war file in a TOMCAT server and “service.bat” file

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9

I developed a Spring boot app and generated the war file in order to deploy it to a TOMCAT cloud server. However, when I did, it didn’t work. It gave me “HTTP Status 404-not found”. So I tried the same steps on a local TOMCAT server. First, it didn’t work too, but when I uninstalled and installed again the “service.bat” file it works fine (it fixed my problem in local).

But my doubt is, making this same procedure in production may affect other apps and result very risky, because other apps are running. There is an additional configuration in the spring Environment to avoid uninstalling an install service.bat.

I show the main function with extends SpringBootServletInitializer I set up:
package com.example.capacitaciones;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CapacitacionesApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CapacitacionesApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(CapacitacionesApplication.class);
    }
}
```

My pom.xml file too

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>capacitaciones</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>capacitaciones</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <finalName>capacitaciones</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Also, the errors i got when i used local TOMCAT server (my first try).
The errors is about port 8080 is in use, but when i changed port it passed same with "8082,8089...". Thats why i tried to eliminating "service.bat">
[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UfjA.jpg)

Comment: Stop mixing versions to start with. Mixing 2.5.4 and 2.6.3 modules is going to blow up. You can also only start the service once, when redeploying you don't call the bat again (or with the proper arguments to restart).

Comment: What happened is: you had another server running on port `8080`. When you tried to connect to your application, you connected to the other server instead. Obviously that server did not have your application. `service.bat` is used only once to install a Windows service (unless you use the MSI installer), afterwards it should not be called again.